# is there any way to initialize numpy array which will contain certain number of element and have shape of (200,200,3)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to make a function that takes a list of resized images (size of image is (200,200)) and convert each picture one by one in the form of numpy array. so in the end i will have main numpy array which contain all the 20 images in the form of numpy array. And in the in the end this function will return numpay array of shape (200,200,3) which contain all pics.

What I have done so far is this:

```
def converttonumpyarray(list_of_resized_images):

    for image in list_of_resized_images:
        array1 = np.array(image).reshape(200,200,3)
        for img in list_of_resized_images:
            array2 = np.array(image).reshape(200,200,3)
            array1 = np.concatenate((array1,array2))
        break

    return array1
```

but reshape function is generating following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 90000 into shape (200,200,3)
```

Kindly, let me know if there is any other way to do this working. Thank you

Comment: What is the original shape of `np.array(image)`?

Comment: I have checked the shape of 'np.array(image)' and that's what i got as an answer: (150, 200, 3)

Comment: Then there's your answer: one of your input images is 150x200 pixels, not 200x200 as you assumed.

Comment: I think an array of 20 images each one's shape is (200, 200, 3) should have a shape of (20*200, 200, 3) which is (4000, 200, 3), isn't that right?

Comment: If you have 20 images each of 200x200 your output array can surely only be (20,200,200) or (200,200,20) but never (200,200,3)?

Comment: @MarkSetchell oh yeah it makes sense, but the required main array sized should be (200,200,3) thats the condition. And that's why I'm looking for ways to do it.

Comment: @Thomas yeah maybe that could be the issue. I'll try to run this script with bigger size images.